# Getting error when running startx in Linux

Tags: linux, x-server

When I am trying to run the Xserver using the command `startx` I am getting the below mentioned error

```
xauth:  creating new authority file /oracle/oracle10g/.serverauth.22555
Fatal server error:
PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
    Perhaps you do not have console ownership?

Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
giving up.
xinit:  unable to connect to X server
xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  unexpected signal 2.
Couldnt get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Do you run it locally or remotely?

Answer (score 1):

have you set your DISPLAY environment variable something like DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 ?
are you root user ? If you are root user and login as normal user you can not start X

Comment: do we need to have xmanager on our remote machine

Comment: @maverick Yes. Or any sort of emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If there is already another X session running, you have to run yours on a different display number. Try this:

```
startx -- :5
```

(Here "5" could be any unused number.)